# Add role in FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I installed FOSUsrBundle. How to add a role from controller to user?

I tried this solution but doesn't work:

```
$user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
$user->addRole('ROLE_USER');
```

Comment: Roles are added on sign up.. You would need to change the role via console.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? How do you know it doesn't work? Are you trying to add it for the current request only or do you want to persist this role to the database?

Comment: change role from console it's ok but I would like to change role from controller (persist this role in database) because I have an interfece admin to manage all user (change role , change name,email ...)

Answer (score 3):

Just add a role choice field with roles list on your userType form.

```
$builder->add('roleList', 'choice', array(
'choices'   => array(
    'ROLE_ADMIN'   => 'ROLE_ADMIN',
    'ROLE_USER' => 'ROLE_USER',
),
'property_path' => false,
'multiple'  => true,
))
```

And in the controller just add this code to add role into user

```
$formData = $this->getRequest()->request->get($form->getName());           
$roles = $formData['roleList'];

foreach($roles as $key => $value)
{
 $user->addRole($value);
}
```

I think this is enough for assign roles into user the user interface.

Comment: Actually, you don't even need to manually add the roles. Just rename `roleList` to `roles` and `FOSUserBundle` should take care of adding the roles for you when you add the user i.e. `$userManager->updateUser($formData->getData())`. This worked for me